# Does Sarkhan Vol planeswalker die after the Eldrazi are freed in Zendikar? (MTG Novel)

Tags: books, magic-the-gathering

I've not had the pleasure of reading Magic The Gathering (MTG) "Teeth of Akoum" Zendikar book yet even though its been around a few years now. I play alot of MTG and Sarkhan Vol is probably one of my favorite Planeswalkers, and I always wonder what has happened to him after he became Sarkhan the mad after Nicol Bolas sent him to Zendikar to await Jace and Chandra at the 'Eye of Ugin' where the Eldrazi had been trapped.

Im aware that the answer may contain possible spoilers, but as Nicol Bolas has the power to bring people back from the dead if he deems them worthy of further use in his master plan, I'm wondering if he would let Sarkhan die/remain dead if he were killed?

Edit: I should note that my prompts for asking this question is not out of laziness to read the book, as quotes from the books appear on the actual game cards as flavour text to give you a taste of the story line which has increased my interest in reading this book. 
Also, often game card's mechanics reflect events that happen within the story. Planeswalkers are god-like mortals (they have they power of a god and can teleport to other planes/dimensions, but can die if mortally wounded). This is reflected in the characters card by the ability to heal itself from injury, but Sarkhan is the *only* planeswalker that has no heal option, his only function is to eventually die if you use him, which is why I asked this question.

[image: Sarkhan Vol (the mad)]

This is the card representing him within the novel (going mad) waiting at the eye of Ugin. The 7 at bottom right is his life and the 3 options down the left side basically kill him when used, normally there would be a +1 option (healing) so that he may live through the use of the minus options.

Comment: If the character is that significant to you, reading the book for the answer will be a better answer than any up-voted answer here.

Comment: Well Ive got the right to ask a question so I'm exercising it. I'm not asking for a blow by blow account of the whole book, and I may never get around to locating a copy, there are 45+ books in this series after all. Its just in the game I use this character quite often and im interested, Im sure all the comic fans who know about the Avengers movie still went to see it, its no different from my question. Still dont know why this would get that many down votes though? Tough crowd lol.

Comment: That was not me being negative, just today alone this has had (-4 votes and +5) for a simple question? Sarkhan is relitively unknown and I'm more curious as to if he is alive in the book still as they may make another version of him for the game which would be awsome. On side note out of the 100+ players I personally know none have read this book, and web pages reguarding this game dont allow questions about none game related issues. As a very eclectic community I thought that this wouldn't be 'offensive'?

Comment: One further thing, although not relivant to just this question either. I'm a new member and have seen so much negativity in this community. Why do people bother down-voting rather then suggesting an edit? As to this question and it -6 votes, If these people are not interested in MTG, why even bother to click on this question? This trends of internet trolling for the sheer hell of it puzzles me? We are all sci fi fans here, why hate on something, I'm not in to Harry  Potter, I see alot of questions- I just dont bother with them. This site is strict on some things where others are rampant.

Comment: Don't take the down votes personally. While the internet will unfailing provide a certain amount of negative feedback when anonymity is available, in this case I would venture to guess that most of the DVs are due to having asked about what happens in a book without having read it first, rather than the topic's relative obscureness.

Comment: Voters! Please consider that Magic: the Gathering DOES not rely on the book readers to know the game, nor the game players to read the books. It appears that @BadMike01 is a player who would like to know about the books. Perhaps he's read some, but hasn't got access to them all. This doesn't seem like an inherently bad question, but it might be improved if the OP let people know what they have tried first (reaserch etc).

Comment: @pureferret thank you for your understanding of the situation. I'm considering an edit of my question. I'll include the sources I HAVE read, people just have to understand the character I'm asking about is like asking a question about one of jedi you see milling about in the back ground of one of the movies, he has a back story but only select people know it.

Comment: @BadMike01 I didn't up/downvote the question either way, but remember that votes are *supposed* to be for whether or not the question is clear, useful and well researched. Based on the info provided, I could see how someone might argue that it was not well researched and downvote it due to that.

Comment: @ phantom42 I understand (now) why I might have prompted so much down voting due to my underestimation of users knowing of the game side to MTG (millions of players worldwide), I was infact basing my question on the fact 'Wizards of the Coast' MTG's owner is a prolific publisher of fantasy novels, who also own Dungeons and Dragons (D&D) to which a fair few novels from that brand have made New York Times best sellers lists, but doesn't necessarily mean the readers know of or even played D&D. Either way, I redoubled my efforts to find the answer after the down votes and found it and a good read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After scouring various web-sites trying to find this answer, and thinking of revising my question to include what I did know of Sarkahn while on Zendikar (from a few comics and from actual flavour text printed on the game cards them selves of which I have the complete set). It turns out while looking back at the comic short stories involving Sarkhan, the publisher had released a second volume of collected stories, one of which I didn't personally have, Which shows Sarkhan the mad (second version in the game) returning to his master Nicol Bolas and informing him of the titanic Eldrazi's release at the 'Eye of Ugin' (a mystical prison hidden within a mountain that constantly changes shape). So this answer would not have been inside the novel after all as it was printed as an additional to the current story arc of the game/novel. Below are are the couple of pages I have based my answer on.

[image: Path of the Planeswalker page]
The above page shows Sarkhan being told he had completed his mission, and the next shows Bolas's other Planeswalker minion Tezzeret being brought back to life by Bolas, who earlier in the comic had told Sarkhan that birth and death are easily reversable if he sees fit, while quoting "Be at ease Sarkhan...I take care of my pawns" which I guess is the answer to my question, yes Sarkhan is alive still and one day in the game I may see a new version of him.
[image: Path of the Planeswalker page]